# Using psql to run a file with both standard query language and meta-commands

Tags: psql

I'm running a command prompt file to open and execute a batch file using psql:

psql -d databasename -h hostname -p portnumber -U username -w -f batchfile\location\here

In the batch file, I can successfully use query language but I'm unsuccessful in running a meta-command.

I'm trying to use both to produce the following:
- Create table foo (Through standard Postgres language)
- Copy a csv file into foo (csv is located on my local drive but sql is on a remote server, thus I'm trying to use the \copy meta command)

I'm running postgreSQL version 8.2.15 on windows 7

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, "\copy invokes COPY FROM STDIN or COPY TO STDOUT, and then fetches/stores the data in a file accessible to the psql client". Maybe try using COPY FROM directly instead. The back-slash might be causing an issue in the batch file. Try something like this in your batch file:

```
COPY foo FROM '/dir/file.csv';
```

This will copy data from a file into the "foo" table: